# Access denied in warehousingwebservice hybris

Tags: postman, sap-commerce-cloud

when calling warehousingwebservice in hybris 1905 it is giving access denied while in 1811 it is not. please assist with what should be changed to solve this problem

[RestHandlerExceptionResolver] Translating exception [org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException]: Access is denied

tried doing

https://answers.sap.com/questions/12758632/there-is-no-resource-for-path-oauthtoken-hybris-60.html

and

https://answers.sap.com/questions/12767378/how-can-we-access-oauth2-using-postman.html

but problem still exists

Comment: what is the url that you access when you get AccessDenied ?

Comment: https://localhost:9002/authorizationserver/oauth/token?client_id=trusted_client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=client_credentials
>> to get token

https://localhost:9002/warehousingwebservices/consignments/cons00001000_1/
>> to access webservice
tried with bearer token authorization, oauth2.0 and basic auth and still same error

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is that you are requesting oauth token for `grant_type=client_credentials` which will give you a token to access non users services. Instead you would need to use `grant_type=password`.

For consignment services, you would need to request a token for authorized users group users for service you need  to access. you would need t provide username and password while making a new token request.

Comment: tried that even using admin user, still access denied error

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to my laptop for a couple of days but as I can remember you can check 2 things to troubleshoot it... A) back office -> oauth tab in left explorer tree and check for configuration B)check for the spring security group applied for the service